# SparkSQL - CassandraSqlContext query on Collection (Set)

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Lets say I have a table like :

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
    userid ascii,
    books set<text>
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);
```

and index :

```
create index on USER (books);
```

I want to query on books by using sql context. What I am doing is :

```
CassandraSQLContext cassandraContext = new CassandraSQLContext(sparkContext);
SchemaRDD userTable = cassandraContext.sql("SELECT * FROM keyspace.user");
userTable.registerTempTable("usertable");
```

Following query does **not** work for Cassandra :

```
SchemaRDD userTable = cassandraContext.sql("SELECT * FROM keyspace.user where books CONTAINS 'book1' and books CONTAINS 'book2'");
```

It returns users with only 'book1'. I've tried similar queries like `books CONTAINS ('book1', 'book2')` but none of them worked.

What I can do on **registered table** is :

```
SchemaRDD users = cassandraContext.sql("SELECT * FROM usertable where userid='some_user_id'");
```

What I want to do is query by books like :

```
SchemaRDD users = cassandraContext.sql("SELECT * FROM usertable where books IN ('book1', 'book2')");
```

or similar queries.

but it doesnt work. It returns 0 records. I tried to register index table named as `user_books_idx` but it didnt work either. Am I able to query on indexed collections? How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the CONTAINS clause only works with one value per statement, so you may not be able to 'and' two different CONTAINS clauses together at one shot.

So I would create one RDD using CONTAINS 'book1', then I'd create another RDD using CONTAINS 'book2', and then I'd do a join of the two RDD's on the userid field.  That should give you a resulting RDD of the users with both book1 and book2 in their books set.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now but its kind of slow. I know its not possible with cql but I was hoping to do it with sql context with some join clause.

Comment: Hi @MustafaGenç.. I have similar problem.. With this I get GenericRow instead of CassandraRow..doing JOINs using schemaRDD temp tables.